# Field Pack Dropdown Channel Form Problem

Tags: ee2, safecracker, field-pack

The following code doesn't work.

```
<label for="intent_of_posting">Intent of Posting</label>
<select name="intent_of_posting" id="intent_of_posting">
    {options:intent_of_posting}
         <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
    {/options:intent_of_posting}
</select>
```

How to make Field Pack Dropdown work with channel form?

Am using EE 2.11.3 and Fieldpack 2.2

Answer (score 0):

The `{options:field_name}` tag pair is actually a Safecracker tag, which only works with Field Pack 1.x out of the box. You can add Field Pack 2.x support by opening up system/expressionengine/config/config.php and adding these lines:

```
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_checkboxes';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_radio_buttons';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_dropdown';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_multiselect';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_pill';
```

Thanks to [Brandon Kelly](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/490/brandon-kelly) for answering the question